# Javascript canvas game development - how to manipulate game piece position

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I created a canvas game for a psych test of agency/sense of control. The game piece is moved left to right on the x axis using the mouse. The purpose is to catch the Xs and Os falling from the top of the screen with the game piece. I used W3Schools canvas game as a starting point (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp).

I am using this to update the position of the game piece:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
})
```

To mess with the sense of control, I am trying to add to the position of the game piece when moved with the mouse...for example, add 5 pixels.

When I try something like

```
myGameArea.x = e.pageX + 5;
```

nothing happens. It doesn't impact the the game piece movement like I hoped.

I've been able to add "lag" to the game piece by using the setTimeout() function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
}, 100);
```

But how do I change the actual position?

Comment: You need to store what the position of the game piece is and create a loop that adds 5 to the position each time.

Comment: @RobBailey Thank you for your suggestion! It makes sense when I read it but not when I try to write it. I can't add to e.pageX but that is what does the movement. Can you show me what you're thinking in code?